# Find tag names and transfer them to an array

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need a way to split a string from a rich-text-box which contains some "tags" like this:

```
<Name>Peter<Type>ABC<Date>20171112
```

As the result, I want something that looks like this:

1. `Name`
2. `Type`
3. `Date`

I don't need the value from between the tags.  I just need the names of the tags within `<` and `>` characters.  I am not really sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)` will work for that.  For instance:

```
Dim input As String = "<Name>Peter<Type>ABC<Date>20171112"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)"
Dim result() As String = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).
    Cast(Of Match).
    Select(Function(m) m.Value).
    ToArray()
```

Here's a overview of how it works:

- `(?<=<)` - A look-behind asserting that matches must be preceded by a `<` character
- `[^>]+` - Matches all text up until the next `>` character
- `(?=>)` - A look-ahead asserting that matches must be followed by a trailing `>` character

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\<(.*?)\>`:

```
Dim input = "<Name>Peter<Type>ABC<Date>20171112"
Dim result As String() = Regex.Matches(input, "\<(.*?)\>").Cast(Of Match)().
    Select(Function(m) m.Value.Trim("<"c, ">"c)).
    ToArray()
```